# Distance measure between two sets of possibly different size

Tags: algorithm, set, distance

I have 2 sets of integers, A and B, not necessarily of the same size. For my needs, I take the distance between each 2 elements a and b (integers) to be just `abs(a-b)`.

I am defining the distance between the two sets as follows:

1. If the sets are of the same size, minimize the sum of distances of all pairs [a,b] (a from A and b from B), minimization over all possible 'pairs partitions' (there are n! possible partitions).
2. If the sets are not of the same size, let's say A of size m and B of size n, with m < n, then minimize the distance from (1) over all subsets of B which are of size m.

My question is, is the following algorithm (just an intuitive guess) gives the right answer, according to the definition written above.

- Construct a matrix `D` of size `m X n`, with `D(i,j) = abs(A(i)-B(j))`
- Find the smallest element of `D`, accumulate it, and delete the row and the column of that element. Accumulate the next smallest entry, and keep accumulating until all rows and columns are deleted.

for example, if `A={0,1,4}` and `B={3,4}`, then `D` is (with the elements above and to the left):

`3 4`

`0` `3 4`

`1` `2 3`

`4` `1 0`

And the distance is `0 + 2 = 2`, coming from pairing `4` with `4` and `3` with `1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that this problem is referred to sometimes as the skis and skiers problem, where you have n skis and m skiers of varying lengths and heights. The goal is to match skis with skiers so that the sum of the differences between heights and ski lengths is minimized.

To solve the problem you could use minimum weight bipartite matching, which requires O(n^3) time.

Even better, you can achieve O(n^2) time with O(n) extra memory using the simple dynamic programming algorithm below.

Optimally, you can solve the problem in linear time if the points are already sorted using the algorithm described in this [paper](http://drum.lib.umd.edu/bitstream/1903/610/2/CS-TR-3199.pdf).

O(n^2) dynamic programming algorithm:

```
if (size(B) > size(A))
  swap(A, B);
sort(A);
sort(B);
opt = array(size(B));
nopt = array(size(B));
for (i = 0; i < size(B); i++)
  opt[i] = abs(A[0] - B[i]);
for (i = 1; i < size(A); i++) {
  fill(nopt, infinity);
  for (j = 1; j < size(B); j++) {
    nopt[j] = min(nopt[j - 1], opt[j - 1] + abs(A[i] - B[j]));
  swap(opt, nopt);
}
return opt[size(B) - 1];
```

After each iteration `i` of the outer `for` loop above, `opt[j]` contains the optimal solution matching `{A[0],..., A[i]}` using the elements `{B[0],..., B[j]}`.

The correctness of this algorithm relies on the fact that in any optimal matching if a1 is matched with b1, a2 is matched with b2, and a1 < a2, then b1 <= b2.

Comment: +1: nice pointing out that the problem has a structure not present in general bipartite matching

Comment: Thanks. Since the maximum size `N` is limited in my use case, I can actually build a table of all distances for all possible sizes between `0` and `N`, and use it in run-time (instead of calculating it in run-time).

Comment: What is the difference between the minimum weight bipartite matching, and the assignment problem mentioned below by @lijie ?

Comment: as far as i know, they are the same (except perhaps for terminology).

Comment: They are two names for the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the optimum, solve the assignment problem on `D`.

The assignment problem finds a perfect matching in a bipartite graph such that the total edge weight is minimized, which maps perfectly to your problem. It is also in P.

**EDIT** to explain how OP's problem maps onto assignment.

For simplicity of explanation, extend the smaller set with special elements `e_k`.

Let A be the set of workers, and B be the set of tasks (the contents are just labels).

Let the cost be the distance between an element in A and B (i.e. an entry of `D`). The distance between `e_k` and anything is 0.

Then, we want to find a perfect matching of A and B (i.e. every worker is matched with a task), such that the cost is minimized. This *is* the assignment problem.

Comment: I can't understand assignment problem relation to this, would you explain what good thing can be achieved by assignment problem? The algorithm `OP` offered selects a perfect matching. if you assume `A` and `B` are parts. I guess this problem is `NP` and if is `P`, has a difficult Dynamic programming approach.

Comment: Assignment finds a perfect matching such that total edge weight is minimized (not just any perfect matching). In other words, OP's problem is also known as the assignment problem (which has a polynomial time solution).

Comment: also, if a problem is in P, it is definitely also in NP (P is a subset of NP).

Comment: At first I think assignment problem is finding matching, but after I see the wiki, I found that your idea is true, but where I said that P is not in NP? and you try to say this? by convention instead of saying NPC I said NP, It's normal convention.

Comment: you didn't say P is not in NP. I misunderstood. I said it is in P, and after that you said "I guess this problem is NP and if..." so I was confused.

Comment: Since my total distance is the sum of distances, does it mean my problem maps to a linear assignment problem?

Comment: Yes, essentially, but jonderry's solution is better (because it is tailored to the extra structure in the problem)

Answer (score 1):

No It's not a best answer, for example:
**A: {3,7}** and **B:{0,4}** you will choose: **{(3,4),(0,7)}** and distance is `8`  but you should choose **{(3,0),(4,7)}** in this case distance is `6`.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer gives a good approximation to the minimum, but not necessarily the best minimum. You are following a "greedy" approach which is generally much easier, and gives good results, but can not guarantee the best answer.